# sql and multiple where query

Tags: sql

I've got an input screen which can take unto 8 input values. The input values are as follows

```
tCustomerIDStart  -  tCustomerIDEnd
tProjectIDStart - tProjectIDEnd
tDateStart - tDateEnd
tProjectStatusStart - tProjectStatusEnd
```

Once the user clicks on submit on my form, I want to perform a query on my SQLite database. The query I have below is a basic outline of what I want however I'm not quite sure how to structure the query if the user only inputs one pair of search criteria e.g. tDateStart - tDateEnd. Can I get the query to omit the other clauses? Does the first clause in the WHERE statement always have to evaluate to true before other clauses are invoked. I can construct a query if all of the fields are filled in, it's mainly a case of using the WHERE syntax and then using AND to build the clauses. However, is it possible for sql to ignore an empty pair of search criteria fields?

```
  "SELECT  project.start_date, project.projectID, project.project_title, customer.customer, " &\
  "project.end_date, project.project_manager, project_status.project_status " &\
  "FROM project " &\
  "LEFT JOIN customer " &\
  "ON project.customerID=customer.customerID " &\
  "LEFT JOIN project_status " &\
  "ON project.project_statusID=project_status.project_statusID " &\
  "WHERE project.projectID BETWEEN " & tProjectIDStart & " AND " & tProjectIDEnd & " " &\
  "OR customer.customerID BETWEEN " & tCustomerIDStart & " AND " & tCustomerIDEnd & " " &\
  "OR project.project_status_id BETWEEN " & tStatusIDStart & " AND " & tStatusIDEnd & " " &\
  "OR project.start_date >= " & tDateStart & " AND " & tDateEnd & " " &\
  "ORDER BY date(project.start_date) ASC "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just build your query based on whether those values are empty or null

if you start your where with something that's always true like `1=1` then you just apply your other filters and start them all with `AND`

```
sql = "SELECT  project.start_date, project.projectID, project.project_title, customer.customer, " &\
  "project.end_date, project.project_manager, project_status.project_status " &\
  "FROM project " &\
  "LEFT JOIN customer " &\
  "ON project.customerID=customer.customerID " &\
  "LEFT JOIN project_status " &\
  "ON project.project_statusID=project_status.project_statusID " &\
  "WHERE 1=1 "

if (tProjectIDStart != "" And tProjectIDEnd != "")
{
    sql = sql & " AND project.projectID BETWEEN " & tProjectIDStart & " AND " & tProjectIDEnd & " "
}
etc.. 

sql = sql &  "ORDER BY date(project.start_date) ASC "
```

Comment: Thank you - thats a neat way of doing it